# How to keep width of SELECT Element small but OPTIONs flexible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Problem:**

My dropdown is loaded dynamically has some options that are quite long and this is messing up my page layout. I'd like the size of the `select` element to be small but when expanded, allow the user to see all the long `options`. To do this I have set the `width` of the `SELECT` to a fixed value e.g `width:200px;`

**Expected/Desired Behavior (Works in Chrome)**

[image]
**Actual Behavior in IE8**

[image]

**What I have tried:**

```
select{
    overflow:show;
}
option{
    overflow:show;
    width:1000px;
}
```

**SIMPLIFIED FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/gCbhq/2/

Comment: so you want options on IE to expand? This is a site for questions after all ;-)

Comment: Looking through my CSS file. I had that problem, too. 1sec

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but look into chosen.js: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ I use it for lots of select boxes, though I'm not sure how well it works in ie8.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar - You jsFiddle is working in my IE8, even in IE7 !! [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/VinPB.png?1)

Comment: @PankitKapadia That is so weird..What sub-version of IE8 are you using? Im using 8.0.6001.18702 on Windows XP. Here's a screenshot :http://i.imgur.com/NOOHs.png?1

Comment: @SajjanSarkar - Actually its ie9. as you can see in screenshot i have changed browser from developer tools. It should work in yours as well.

Comment: @PankitKapadia It doesnt, thats the point of this question.

Comment: { overflow: show; } ??? i just now { overflow: visible; }

Answer (score 11):

Ok. Not sure if this helps. I'm using Jquery Mobile and my select button is icon-only (= 28px). On IE8 all my options hence where 28px, too.

I fixed it with this:

```
select { min-width: 150px !important; }
```

but this only works, because Jquery Mobile hides the select and adds it's own elements "on top".

Alas, here is a fix - http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/

Comment: please check this answer if it helped!

Comment: setting the min-width did not work. And changing the width of the select to auto on hover is again bringing us back to the same original problem (ruins my layout as it pushes against the adjacent items)
+1 for the idea and the link

Comment: ok. Let me think some more. Nothing I know out of the box though... IE8 is just nobodys friend...

Answer (score 6):

All you can do for this is hack it so it looks close.  Chrome behavior cannot be emulated just by adding/altering CSS of the `select` alone.

This is as close as you can get without adding any other elements:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/SelectCutoffFix/
(click back to the article at the top for the implementation details)

The above solution is the best you can do with what you're asking for, which is no additional elements on around the `select`.

If you're willing to add a `div` with a little styling around the `select`(no replacement or special UI widgets), you can make it look a little better:

http://www.getharvest.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/select_box_demo.html

(details here: http://www.getharvest.com/blog/2009/12/dropdown-problems-on-internet-explorer/)

That solution is about as close as I've seen to doing what you're looking for.  That being said it is a hack, and has some issues:

- if you select the same `option` twice in a row, expected behavior doesn't kick in until focus leaves the `select`
- when the `select` is open, the down arrow button disappears (because the overflow is being hidden by the enclosing div)

The above solutions will get you a bit closer, but neither of them look as polished as I'd like them to be.  If you're unable to add anything else to the page, however, these are going to be your best options(based on countless hours of researching this in the past).  Yeah it sucks, but we're all in the same boat.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, the css-tricks solution was already proposed by frequent above and wont work for me as it pushes against the adjacent elements when the select is hovered upon.

The getharvest.com one was quite interesting to go trhu,just another reaffirmation that hacking takes tremendous skill too!I never thought this was gonna b so difficult.When I posted tis question I thought I was gonna get an answer (and some criticism for posting a simple question) within a few minutes.Thank you for your time on this, I will let the question remain open & if nth will accept ur answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a exact solution but you can give this little html and css hack to achieve your goal.
**HTML**

```
<div class="divWrapper">
 <select class="selectBox">
 <option>011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112</option>
 <option>011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112</option>
 <option>011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112</option>
 <option>011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112</option>
 </select>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divWrapper{
    width:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

.selectBox{
    width:150px;
    }

.selectBox:focus{
    width:auto;
    }
```

Here we are wrapping the selectbox with a div which width must be equal to selectbox div. And on focus of selectbox making it again to auto width.

if you can want jquery use jquery portion. It will resize the width of selectbox as you defined when you select any option.
Check it out on http://jsfiddle.net/sudhanshu414/5NEWc/2/

Comment: Thanks, similar approaches have been suggested above.
Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i use as a pure css solution to this problem. If focusing on the select pushing any other page elements I simply z-index the select:focus. Also you can set the select:focus width to auto if you want, it will still work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<style type="text/css">
select:focus {width:300px;}
.cover select {width: 150px;} 
</style>

  </head>
  <body>


<div class="cover">
<select>
 <option>Select Box</option>
 <option>Option One a line of text</option>
 <option>Option Two a longer line of text</option>
 <option>Option Three is a much longer line of text</option>
 <option>Option Four </option>
</select>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

If you remove the class "cover" and just style the select, the select will also resize on focus. so you have options as to which way you want it to display.

this has been tested in the newest version of chrome, firefox, and IE

Comment: This does not work in IE8.I havent tried in other IE versions.here's a fiddle with your code:http://jsfiddle.net/3fATn/1/

Comment: using IE9 developer tools tested in ie7 and ie8 mode, also cranked up my old laptop and tested in the IE8 version on there. Worked in every one. Could you please elaborate on what exactly it is not doing correctly in your browser. Maybe a screen shot if you could, and I will get it to work.

Comment: It works on IE9 in every mode. It does not work on IE8.
Here's a screenshot of the fiddle i made with your code:http://i.imgur.com/99vjZ.png?1

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the behavior but you could try in css this:

```
select:focus{width:auto !important;}
```

But you also could take a look at [JQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

[EDIT-1-]: I tried to reproduce the unexpected behavior of IE. In 7/8/9 I cannot see the problem. Perhaps you're working with a really old IE? Try running an update for version 8 if it is possible.

What you want to do, is far reaching. I don't think you can access the children altering their appearance and meanwhile keeping the SELECT-parent at a normal size. You would need to decouple both elements. You could try to implement an own solution for a dropdown-list but as it seems to be the normal behavior for other browsers like other IE-editions, Chrome etc. this could be a waste of work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').click( function () { 
     //Try to alter the css here - but I'm not sure if this could work.
  });
```

[EDIT-2-]: A [select-menu for JQuery-UI](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu) is planned. But if you consider other JQuery plugins you could use [dropkick.js](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/) or [take a look at this list](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/).

Comment: This does not achieve what I'm looking for.Its widening the select element on focus which is pushing against the adjacent elements.I want the SELECT itself to be constant width.Thank you for your time though :)

Comment: Thank you again. Yes i knew this was a hard problem, that's why I wanted to get others' opinions before deciding it is not possible at all. And again ur right, there is no way to decouple the OPTION elements from the SELECT w.r.t layout. I am getting this behavior in IE8(all updates installed)

Answer (score 0):

Not going with CSS alone in IE, because it is more or less a OS-widget you want to style.

Try a selectBox, which uses JavaScript to insert some HTML and JavaScript to mimick the bahaviour of select but with other HTML markup

https://github.com/revsystems/jQuery-SelectBox or here
http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/

Comment: As i said in my bounty note, Im NOT looking for components which mimick the select box. Im trying to see if there is a native HTML/CSS way to achieve this effect using the orignial select element. Your solution mimics it using DIVs.

Comment: In that case you are unlucky. I cannot think about a solution that will work with this "antique" browser.