# Dropdown autosize select in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to autosize just the dropdown list in a angularjs listbox?
I don't want the top part to resize, just the dropdown.

Something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90wnW.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep width of SELECT Element small but OPTIONs flexible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885924/how-to-keep-width-of-select-element-small-but-options-flexible)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this html and css code as your basis to solve your problem.

**Markup**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<select class="dropdown">
<option>Option1</option>
<option>Option2</option>
<option>Option3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
width:150px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.dropdown{
width:150px;
}

.dropdown:focus{
width:auto;
}
```